# Send Email in .Net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email, sendmail, sendmessage

I need to send a basic email from my site when someone registers for my site.  Is their an easy way?  or a site to reference?

Comment: This is the kind of question that might be faster to search online (Google) than to ask on Stack Overflow. Oh well, maybe someone's Google search will hit this question to find the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

[SmtpClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx)

and

[MailMessage Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx)

[HOW TO: Send email using System.Net.Mail](http://forums.asp.net/t/971802.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

See an example [here](http://www.example-code.com/vbdotnet/SimpleSendHtmlEmail.asp). There are also some more advanced [examples](http://www.example-code.com/vbdotnet/email.asp) available.

Answer (score 0):

The [Web Application Toolkit for Template-Driven Email](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WebAppToolkitEmail)  from the MSDN Code Gallery may be worth a look as well...